# Is it okay to ask a question in order to identify an extraterrestrial-like pattern?

Tags: discussion

In Google Maps satellite mode I saw an odd pattern on the ground as if extraterrestrial creatures -if they exist- have created it!

Is it okay to ask to identify these patterns in the site?

Answer (score 4):

Personally I think it's fine if you want to ask "what is it" questions about locations on the Earth.  However, I would refrain from attributing any features to "extraterrestrials". Instead, try to do real research about what it could be and include your findings in the question.

Comment: Of course I don't know if that pattern I'm speaking about is natural or man-made. Is it still on-topic? It's more likely to be man-made;  but it's so strange, and I don't know what its purpose is.

Comment: If it looks like a natural feature on Earth, I think it's fine to ask "what is it".